# Projection systems mismatched

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, netcdf

[image: OSM standard base layer and climate raster layer]

I was planning on importing a temperature file (in NetCDF format) as a raster layer. Here is the link of the temperature data (https://psl.noaa.gov/data/gridded/data.cpc.globaltemp.html). The data site does not provide information on projection system.

However, the layers seem to be mismatched, and I cannot figure out how to fix this.

Currectly, the base map layer, the red coordinate layer, and the raster layer are all in ESPG4326 WGS 84

Answer (score 0):

Your base map layer goes from -170 Longitude to + 190 Longitude. These are wild guesses, but will work for the explanation. The raster data goes from 0 Longitude to +359 Longitude.

You will have to choose layers that all use the same paradigm. This is a common problem when working with data on a global scale.

There may be tools to transform the raster image, as it wouldn't be that hard programmatically. You could try FME, it does just about everything and has a very useful trial period.